# Deleting nth delimiter in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to delete the 5th delimiter in this string:

```
"Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Rumino_coccaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
```

so it becomes:

```
"Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Ruminococcaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
```

This seems to work, but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution possibly with regex and str_replace

```
library(stringr)
name <- "Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Rumino_coccaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
index <- str_locate_all(name, "_")[[1]]
str_sub(name, index[5, "start"], index[5, "end"]) <- ""
name
```

Comment: Do you mean that you literally want to just delete the fifth underscore ("_")  from the string? Or do you want to split the string into two strings before/after the fifth underscore? Or something else?

Comment: ^The former, sorry I edited my post for more clarity

Comment: Since this is closed, I can't provide a proper 'answer'. However, this should work:

`gsub("((?:[^_]+_){4}[^_]+)_", "\\1", name)`

(where `name` is the string you defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gsub`:

```
> gsub("((?:[^_]+_){4}[^_]+)_", "\\1", name)
[1] "Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Ruminococcaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
>
```

Or a less "pretty" way:

```
> gsub("([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*)_", "\\1", name)
[1] "Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Ruminococcaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
>
```

Or with the **`strex`** library:

```
> library(strex)
> paste(str_before_nth(name, "_", 5), str_after_nth(name, "_", 5), sep="")
[1] "Bacteria_Firmicutes_Clostridia_Clostridiales_Ruminococcaceae_Ruminococcus_Ruminococcus_albus"
>
```